# How to open Google Play Music app from another app on iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, google-music

I need to open Google Play Music app from my app and if it's not installed, open app store page. The latter works. For other music apps I have found the deep link schema like "spotify:" which opens the app.

Is there similar schema supported by Google Music app?

Answer (score 0):

`googleplaymusic://i` - this should work. The "i" can be replaced with anything. You may or may not need it depending on your use.